# Add Reserved IP to existing VM on azure

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I have resource group "cbp.resourcegroup.neu" both my reserved  IP and VM are in the same resource group 
my reserved ip name is CBPIP-Dev-NEU
service name for my machine VM is testmachine which i have taken from as first part of DNS name "testmachine.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"

when i am running the following command to add reserved ip to VM

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName Group cbp.resourcegroup.neu 
CBPIP-Dev-NEU -ServiceName portrtestmachine
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation : Cannot validate argument on parameter 
'Slot'. The argument "CBPIP-Dev-NEU" does not belong to the set 
"Staging,Production" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an 
argument that is in 
the set and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... ion -ReservedIPName Group cbp.resourcegroup.neu CBPIP-Dev-NEU -Servic 
...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.SetAzureReservedIPAssociationCmdlet
```

IS there anything i am missing in my command . I using powershell to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Group cbp.resourcegroup.neu CBPIP-Dev-NEU
```

The spaces make the command think you are using positional paramters, so "CBPIP-Dev-NEU" is being passed to the -Slot parameter, for which that is not a valid value.

Try this instead

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName "CBPIP-Dev-NEU" -ServiceName "portrtestmachine"
```

Comment: No it didnt work. here is the error."Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found."

Comment: That simply means you are giving the command the wrong name, double check what the resource is called, but the command is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

Azure reserved IP can only be assigned to a deployed **PRODUCTION** instance.

But that's useless, cause CloudServices **already** have static IP.

We should check the cloud service, make sure there is no static Public IP address.